# How can I get my invert up/down axis setting to stick?

Tags: splinter-cell-conviction

Every time I restart Splinter Cell: Conviction the mouse is uninverted, forcing me to open the settings menu and enable y axis inversion. This is incredibly annoying. Can I get the game to remember that I've inverted the mouse?

Comment: In other games where I've seen this kind of issue, it's a permissions problem writing the config file.  I believe the settings files are in `C:\ProgramData\Ubisoft\Conviction\` or similar for this game.  This is a "shared between users" directory.  I'd either try looking at the permissions of the .ini files, or running the program as administrator (at least to change the settings - shouldn't be required otherwise)

Comment: @agent86 unfortunately running as Administrator didn't work. Other settings save properly, too.

Comment: Have you tried saving after changing the setting?

Comment: @Brok3n I'm not aware of any explicit "save" functionality in the game. I did play the game after inverting Y axis many times, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might just try a small piece of 3rd party software that inverts the mouse all the time, [like this guy did](http://forums.ubi.com/archive/index.php/t-593223.html).  A bootstrap, but possibly less frustrating than fixing it every time.

You are not the only person with this problem.  Others have tried [manual modification](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1355823) of the .ini agent86 suggests without luck, but as he suggests you may have better success by modifying settings in game when running in admin mode.

Comment: Launching a program every time I launch the game sounds about the same as changing that setting every time I launch the game.

Comment: @kotekzot You could run both from a .bat pretty easily.  Like I said - it's a bootstrap, not pretty.  This games been out for quite a while, so I think the hope of a developer fix is pretty slim.  It seems to be a genuine bug, based on others on the web having the same issue.  Maybe you'd have better luck playing it on a console like I did :).